# このDVD面白かったら、よかったら見てみない。

Tags: meaning, conversations

> このDVD面白かったら、よかったら見てみない。
>
> a-ありがとう、見てみるね
> b-ありがとう、見てみようね

Can someone explain why a is correct and b is incorrect?
As far as I know, when you use ない it is 誘い・提案 - invitation, suggestion for 一緒にする

so if its a invitation for 'us' I assumed it would be b, where よう means sure lets watch it together.

Comment: 見てみない is more like "you should check it out", or "you should give it a try"; not "how about watching it together".

Comment: @A.Ellett
Roger, but how about this use of ない：
A: 食事しない？
B: うん、そうしよう。
A is saying lets eat, and B is saying sure, lets eat.  So your assumption of ない is wrong, correct?

Comment: No.  I don't agree.  (Part 1) Using negation is indeed a way of inviting someone to do something.  But it's often used in a context where in English we would ask "do you want to ..." or "what would you like to do?"  Those questions are potentially too direct and very possibly rude in Japanese.

Comment: (Part 2) They didn't say just みない.  They said みてみない which is much more like "Give it a look-see" or "Give it a try" than anything else.  If the phrase were just よかったら見ない, I might agree with you.  But, I'm not so sure that makes as much sense.

Comment: (Part 3) Both answers start with ありがとう.  That means the respondent received something (something more than a mere *invitation* if you still insists it's an invitation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"見てみない?" does not necessary mean "let's see/watch it together". Besides, the second person said ありがとう, which indicates the first person **lent** the DVD to the second person. If this scene were of two people in the same room discussing what to watch now, saying ありがとう would be unnatural.